# Confusion Over Last Scene of Inception

Tags: inception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At which dream level did Inception end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/at-which-dream-level-did-inception-end)

Was Leonardo DiCaprio dreaming in the last scene of the movie Inception or was that happened in reality?

Comment: The possible duplicate question is phrased differently, but is essentially an exact duplicate.  If you need any additional points to be made, it might be best if they are done there rather than beginning a new question.

Comment: There's an even better set of answers to this in http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6903/interpreting-the-end-of-inception