# How do Cobb's children know which hotel he's staying at in Kyoto in Inception

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

After the failed extraction of information from Saito, Cobb claims that he's "getting off at Kyoto" and we later see him in a hotel room. He spins his totem--the top--to make sure he isn't dreaming, and then receives a call from his children.

**How do they know where he's staying?** As his father-in-law (Michael Caine) later says,

> It'll take more than the occasional stuffed animal to convince these children they still have a father.

So we know he isn't in contact with them a lot. Additionally, he wouldn't want to risk making a call to the United States where he is still wanted for murdering his wife.

Comment: This guy can pull strings to make sure he has cotch (and safe!) digs to stay in - he checks out via a rooftop helicopter for starters! (which was supposed to be a private charter - remember he had no idea Saito was waiting for him up there)

Answer (score 1):

It's never explained in the movie.

However, the movie shows Saito as being a very powerful and wealthy man [as discussed here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/71739/how-does-saito-eliminate-cobbs-murder-charge), so it would be easy for Saito to arrange for someone else to contact the father-in-law and give him Cobb's hotel number.

Unless [the whole movie is a dream](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/10429/when-did-the-inception-start)... But we'll never know that.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *scheduled* telephone call. Clearly Cobb has given his mother-in-law his contact details (possibly via his father-in-law, Professor Miles, who's evidently still in contact with his ex-wife and Dom's children) and arranged to speak to his children at a specific time, hence why he's impatiently sat in his hotel room next to the telephone, checking his watch.

> INT. APARTMENT, TOKYO - CONTINUOUS
>
> **Cobb sits, waiting. Checks his watch, restless.** He pulls a
> HANDGUN. Checks it is loaded. places it on the table in front
> of him. Pulls out a PEWTER SPINNING TOP, SPINS it on the
> table ... He INTENT STUDIES the top's spin... As he stares,
> the sound of a FREIGHT TRAIN builds and builds- the top
> WOBBLES, TIPS onto its side- the sound of the train STOPS.
> **the PHONE RINGS- Cobb GRABS it-**
>
> **CHILDREN'S VOICES (over phone):** *Hi, Daddy! Hi, Dad.*