# Was Cobb really stuck in the dream world at the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

In the movie [*Inception*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/), at the end, the spinning top is shown to be spinning at the end just before the screen goes blank. But another person told me that the top wasnt even *Cobb*'s totem, it is his wife's (*Mal*'s) so he is not in the dream world. Is he?

Comment: Your question seems to cover the same territory as [this one](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2324/at-which-dream-level-did-inception-end).  Is your question answered there?

Comment: thank you:) ive been searching for the answer for a long time