# What was Cobb's original totem?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

In [Inception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception), Cobb uses his dead wife Mal's totem. It is not clearly mentioned or shown what was Cobb's original totem? Or did I miss something? Help please.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1410/49. Other highly related questions: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1832/49 and http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3302/49.

Comment: Good catch of related questions @NapoleonWilson.  The first does ask the identical question at the end.  However it asks that only tangentially to it's main question of **why Cobb switched** from his totem to his wife's totem.  This question seems to me not to be a duplicate and belongs as a separate question.  Note that it would be possible to answer either without answering the other.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone If it can be reworded, I'd vote to reopen.